# Dealing with unescaped strings

Tags: autocad, dde, autolisp

I wrote an alternative fonction to open AutoCAD drawings. However, AutoCAD made it really hard to change how a document is opened when it is ran from Windows Explorer (double click the file with file association). The only method I found is to change a registry key which is "OpenDdeExec". There is a supplied argument (%1) that gives me a unescaped path to the file to open.

I need to ignore the escaping in path or replace the backslashes with double backslashes before it gets parsed as being special characters. In C#, you could do something like `string s = @"I\Like random\backslashes";` and backslashes would be taken as the actualy backslashe character. In lisp, the only equivalence I found is `quote` which has a weird behavior (since it's normal use isn't exactly what I'm trying to acheive).

If I write something like `(quote (I\Like random\backslashes))`, the outcome will be `(I\\Like random\\backslashes)` which is ALMOST what I need. However, I have to get rid of the parenthesis. Any idea how I can acheive this?

Note: Doing this `(quote I\Like random\backslashes)` will break due to the space. It would, however, work on `(quote I\Like\backslashes)`. This would output `I\\Like\\backslashes` just like I want.

This is the current OpenDdeExec with the described issue:

```
(OPENFROMSHELL (QUOTE (%1)))
```

Comment: In Common Lisp such symbols can be defined using | character, like this: `(quote |I\Like random\backslashes|)`. Don't know, if it will work in autolisp though.

Comment: The other things to try may be `(intern "I\Like random\backslashes")` or `(make-symbol "I\Like random\backslashes")`

Comment: Also both unexisting. I ended up writing a little interop application to launch AutoCAD and run the command. Thanks for the suggestion however!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible with AutoCAD's limited LISP.